# Metrics server fails to pull metrics from Windows workers

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, metrics-server

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 Windows worker nodes. When I run `kubectl top nodes` the Windows nodes report as unknown. I did some investigating and I am seeing errors in the logs.

Logs from metric server

```
E0529 12:04:50.809303       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 7d7489daf4b889d4b55d7889a617017768035b7c1c43e8cef5ac0210e7b2ac65: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 12:05:50.838175       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 7d7489daf4b889d4b55d7889a617017768035b7c1c43e8cef5ac0210e7b2ac65: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 12:06:50.815777       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 7d7489daf4b889d4b55d7889a617017768035b7c1c43e8cef5ac0210e7b2ac65: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 12:07:50.800927       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 7d7489daf4b889d4b55d7889a617017768035b7c1c43e8cef5ac0210e7b2ac65: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 12:08:50.821804       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 7d7489daf4b889d4b55d7889a617017768035b7c1c43e8cef5ac0210e7b2ac65: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 12:09:12.819567       1 reststorage.go:135] unable to fetch node metrics for node "qa-k8sw-win-02": no metrics known for node
E0529 12:09:12.819592       1 reststorage.go:135] unable to fetch node metrics for node "qa-k8sw-win-01": no metrics known for node
E0529 12:09:50.809012       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 7d7489daf4b889d4b55d7889a617017768035b7c1c43e8cef5ac0210e7b2ac65: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 12:10:53.085842       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = container 29f403ebb265389ac1bcbe39f8a555045e1e461a2abf065f11d2f8b267f83b12 encountered an error during Properties: failure in a Windows system call: A system shutdown is in progress. (0x45b)"]
E0529 12:12:00.147458       1 reststorage.go:135] unable to fetch node metrics for node "qa-k8sw-win-02": no metrics known for node
E0529 12:12:00.147485       1 reststorage.go:135] unable to fetch node metrics for node "qa-k8sw-win-01": no metrics known for node
E0529 12:12:44.741135       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): Get https://10.4.111.68:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: context deadline exceeded]
E0529 12:13:44.740851       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): Get https://10.4.111.68:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: context deadline exceeded]
E0529 12:14:44.740965       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): Get https://10.4.111.68:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: context deadline exceeded]
E0529 12:15:44.740936       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): Get https://10.4.111.68:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: context deadline exceeded]
```

I saw an error trying to fetch the metrics so from the node running the metrics server pod (`qa-k8sm-02` I ran `curl -v -k https://10.4.111.68:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true`

```
curl -v -k https://10.4.111.68:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true
* About to connect() to 10.4.111.68 port 10250 (#0)
*   Trying 10.4.111.68...
* Connected to 10.4.111.68 (10.4.111.68) port 10250 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=qa-k8sw-win-02@1589888891
*       start date: May 19 10:48:10 2020 GMT
*       expire date: May 19 10:48:10 2021 GMT
*       common name: qa-k8sw-win-02@1589888891
*       issuer: CN=qa-k8sw-win-02-ca@1589888890
> GET /stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 10.4.111.68:10250
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 12:30:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 12
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
<
* Connection #0 to host 10.4.111.68 left intact
```

The connection to the server worked so I looked closer at the error and it was a 500 so I thought there was an issue with the pod on the Windows server so I views the logs of `cattle-node-agent-windows-gkrf9`

```
WARN: Default docker named pipe is not found
WARN: Please bind mount in the docker named pipe to //./pipe/docker_engine if docker errors occur
WARN: example: docker run -v //./pipe/custom_docker_named_pipe://./pipe/docker_engine ...
INFO: https://rancher.mycompany.com is accessible
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Rancher agent version v2.4.3 is starting"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Listening on /tmp/log.sock"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Option etcd=false"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Option controlPlane=false"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Option worker=true"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Option requestedHostname=qa-k8sw-win-02"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Option customConfig=map[address:10.4.111.68 internalAddress: label:map[rke.cattle.io/windows-build:17763 rke.cattle.io/windows-kernel-version:17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434 rke.cattle.io/windows-major-version:10 rke.cattle.io/windows-minor-version:0 rke.cattle.io/windows-release-id:1809 rke.cattle.io/windows-version:10.0.17763.1098] roles:[worker] taints:[]]"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Connecting to wss://rancher.mycompany.com/v3/connect with token qt6xtcslz7gwrjfw5tszj8r5tjrjpqk5kwnfqm85l7wc64tkjwfcqj"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Connecting to proxy" url="wss://rancher.mycompany.com/v3/connect"
time="2020-05-29T07:12:09-05:00" level=info msg="Starting plan monitor, checking every 120 seconds"
```

So I didn't see any errors there so I logged into the Windows server and started looking at container logs and when I viewed the logs for the kubelet I saw a bunch of errors...

```
E0529 18:01:50.824959       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 29f403ebb265389ac1bcbe39f8a555045e1e461a2abf065f11d2f8b267f83b12: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
E0529 18:02:50.797328       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-02: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-02 (10.4.111.68): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem 29f403ebb265389ac1bcbe39f8a555045e1e461a2abf065f11d2f8b267f83b12: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist.", unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:qa-k8sw-win-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet qa-k8sw-win-01 (10.4.111.189): request failed - "500 Internal Server Error", response: "Internal Error: failed to list pod stats: failed to list all container stats: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = hcsshim::OpenComputeSystem cf9d0d43c099624bbbb13cb4a607ca3a818a66aad1631897d47e1c66827782ac: A virtual machine or container with the specified identifier does not exist."]
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with windows. Read github issues. There are bunch of them explaining how to solve this specific scenario.

Comment: @suren Do you have any links?

Comment: there are several. This one, for example. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/299. Might not look like the same, but you will need to configure the tls connection.

Comment: @suren Thanks but the metrics are reported for the linux nodes just fine, only the Windows workers are not reporting or show errors.

Comment: really? ok. sorry for confusing you.

Comment: what is the k8s version (server and client) ? Heas it ever been working or it was not working from the beginning?

Comment: @Nick It was working on one cluster for a short period and it has never worked on the second cluster. Both clusters are set up the same way. Client Version: v1.16.0 Server Version: v1.17.5